# alert do JavaScript Não funciona no Firefox e Chrome

Tags: javascript, .net

Estou tentando gerar um alerta de senha errada em JavaScript.
É para uma aplicação web que funciona em .net.
Este alerta funciona no IE, mas estamos portando o sistema e queria que funcionasse tanto no IE quanto no Firefox e Chrome.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "js", "alert('Senha incorreta para o usuário " + txtLogin.Text + "');", true);
```

Comment: Verifica se os navegadores estão com javascript habilitados, ou melhor, tenta executar a tua aplicação em outro pc e ver o se o erro persiste.

Comment: O javascript já está habilitado nos navegadores, tanto que outras funcionalidades do js funciona. Também já foi testado em outro pc, erro continua. Creio que é alguma especificação deste comando.

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? O código aparece no corpo da página? Já tentou colocar `javascript:alert`? E acrescentar a tag `<script>` e setar o próximo parâmetro como `false`? São algumas soluções que encontrei na net.

Comment: Tentei todas essas combinações possível.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi trocando o comando, continuando achando que este comando RegisterStartupScript não existe no firefox e chrome.
Agora mudei para:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Senha incorreta para o usuário " + txtLogin.Text + "');", true);
```